# Why do I get 'NoneType' object is not iterable in this recursive function

Tags: python

I try to make an algorithm which implements Pattern search (optimization). I'm almost done. Running my algo I see how values converge to the minimum of a function. The only problem I have is this notorious error: `'NoneType' object is not iterable`. My main function looks like this:

```
def exploresearch(xk, yk,  hx, hy, lamb, theta, curval):
  if hx < theta and hy < theta:
    return [xk, yk]
  else:
    while hx > theta and hy > theta:
        # шаг вправо
        if broyden(xk + hx, yk) < curval:
            # шаг вверх
            if broyden(xk + hx, yk + hy) < curval:
                xn = xk + lamb * hx
                yn = yk + lamb * hy
                xk = xk + hx
                yk = yk + hy
                newval = broyden(xk, yk)
                xs, ys, flag = simpleexplore(xn, yn,  hx, hy, lamb, theta, newval) 
                if flag:
                    xk, yk = repeatpattern(xk, yk, hx, hy, xs, ys, lamb, theta)
                xk, yk = exploresearch(xk, yk,  hx, hy, lamb, theta, broyden(xk, yk))
                #repeatexplore(xk, yk, hx, hy, lamb, theta, "+", "+")
            # шаг вниз
            elif broyden(xk + hx, yk - hy) < curval:
                xn = xk + lamb * hx
                yn = yk - lamb * hy
                xk = xk + hx
                yk = yk - hy
                newval = broyden(xk, yk)
                xs, ys, flag = simpleexplore(xn, yn,  hx, hy, lamb, theta, newval) 
                if flag:
                    xk, yk = repeatpattern(xk, yk, hx, hy, xs, ys, lamb, theta)
                xk, yk = exploresearch(xk, yk,  hx, hy, lamb, theta, broyden(xk, yk))
                #repeatexplore(xk, yk, hx, hy, lamb, theta, "+", "-")
            # остаемся
            else:
                #поиск по образцу
                # (xn, yn) - вершина, в которой делаем поиск по образцу
                hy = hy / 2
                xn = xk + lamb * hx
                yn = yk
                xk = xk + hx
                yk = yk
                newval = broyden(xk, yk)
                xs, ys, flag = simpleexplore(xn, yn,  hx, hy, lamb, theta, newval) 
                if flag:
                    xk, yk = repeatpattern(xk, yk, hx, hy, xs, ys, lamb, theta)
                xk, yk = exploresearch(xk, yk,  hx, hy, lamb, theta, broyden(xk, yk))
                #repeatexplore(xk, yk, hx, hy, lamb, theta, "+", "")
        # шаг влево
        elif broyden(xk - hx, yk) < curval:
            # шаг вверх
            if broyden(xk - hx, yk + hy) < curval:
                xn = xk - lamb * hx
                yn = yk + lamb * hy
                xk = xk - hx
                yk = yk + hy
                newval = broyden(xk, yk)
                xs, ys, flag = simpleexplore(xn, yn,  hx, hy, lamb, theta, newval) 
                if flag:
                    xk, yk = repeatpattern(xk, yk, hx, hy, xs, ys, lamb, theta)
                xk, yk = exploresearch(xk, yk,  hx, hy, lamb, theta, broyden(xk, yk))
                #repeatexplore(xk, yk, hx, hy, lamb, theta, "-", "+")
            # шаг вниз
            elif broyden(xk - hx, yk - hy) < curval:
                xn = xk - lamb * hx
                yn = yk - lamb * hy
                xk = xk - hx
                yk = yk - hy
                newval = broyden(xk, yk)
                xs, ys, flag = simpleexplore(xn, yn,  hx, hy, lamb, theta, newval) 
                if flag:
                    xk, yk = repeatpattern(xk, yk, hx, hy, xs, ys, lamb, theta)
                xk, yk = exploresearch(xk, yk,  hx, hy, lamb, theta, broyden(xk, yk))
                #repeatexplore(xk, yk, hx, hy, lamb, theta, "-", "-")
            # остаемся
            else:
                #поиск по образцу
                # (xn, yn) - вершина, в которой делаем поиск по образцу
                hy = hy / 2
                xn = xk - lamb * hx
                yn = yk
                xk = xk - hx
                yk = yk
                newval = broyden(xk, yk)
                xs, ys, flag = simpleexplore(xn, yn,  hx, hy, lamb, theta, newval) 
                if flag:
                    xk, yk = repeatpattern(xk, yk, hx, hy, xs, ys, lamb, theta)
                xk, yk = exploresearch(xk, yk,  hx, hy, lamb, theta, broyden(xk, yk))
                #repeatexplore(xk, yk, hx, hy, lamb, theta, "-", "")
        # шаг вверх
        elif broyden(xk, yk + hy) < curval:
            hx = hx / 2
            xn = xk
            yn = yk + lamb * hy
            xk = xk
            yk = yk + hy
            newval = broyden(xk, yk)
            xs, ys, flag = simpleexplore(xn, yn,  hx, hy, lamb, theta, newval) 
            if flag:
                xk, yk = repeatpattern(xk, yk, hx, hy, xs, ys, lamb, theta)
            xk, yk = exploresearch(xk, yk,  hx, hy, lamb, theta, broyden(xk, yk))
            #repeatexplore(xk, yk, hx, hy, lamb, theta, "", "+")
        # шаг вниз
        elif broyden(xk, yk - hy) < curval:
            hx = hx / 2
            xn = xk
            yn = yk - lamb * hy
            xk = xk
            yk = yk - hy
            newval = broyden(xk, yk)
            xs, ys, flag = simpleexplore(xn, yn,  hx, hy, lamb, theta, newval) 
            if flag:
                xk, yk = repeatpattern(xk, yk, hx, hy, xs, ys, lamb, theta)
            xk, yk = exploresearch(xk, yk,  hx, hy, lamb, theta, broyden(xk, yk))
        else:
            hx = hx / 2
            hy = hy / 2
            xk, yk = exploresearch(xk, yk,  hx, hy, lamb, theta, broyden(xk, yk))
```

Putting some print statements to debug, I see that this error pops up right before while loop. And just before that I print `hy` and `hx` values - and they look normal, just ordinary float numbers. So, at this point I do not know what to do.

Comment: Wonder why people are voting down without giving any hint or comment.

Comment: possibly because you don't include a stack trace, your indentation is wrong, and you don't show any effort in debugging other than saying you added a print statement. Because of that, it's a fairly low quality question. I wasn't the person who downvoted, so that's just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code fails the first test and enters the while loop, you never return anything. If you don't return anything, then statements like this:

```
xk, yk = exploresearch(...)
```

... will throw the error you say it does. That is because `exploresearch(...)` returns `None`, and `xk, yk = None` is trying to iterate over `None` (which is an object of type `NoneType`).

You need to make sure that the `else` portion of your code returns something other than `None`.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I followed your hint and did it.